# The present perfect/the present perfect continuous and the past simple

Tags: past-tense

Would it be wrong to use the past simple, the present perfect, and the present perfect continuous in these sentences after changing   "now" into "today" to say that   I am standing outside the house right now and I am leaving it?

1. "I'm moving to a new house today I lived here for twenty years! I'll really miss it."

2."I'm moving to a new house today. I have lived here for twenty years! I'll really miss it."

3."I'm moving to a new house today. I have been living here for twenty years! I'll really miss it."

Or

"I am moving to a new office today. I have been working here/I have worked here/I worked her for twenty years. I'll really miss it." In this situation as well can I change "today" into "now" to mean that I am leaving the office building right now?  I am standing outside the office and I am leaving it.

Comment: (2) and (3) are both acceptable. You would only say _I lived here_ after you have moved to another address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [have lived in (for,since)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/132449/have-lived-in-for-since)

Comment: No, it doesn't answer my question. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "I lived here for twenty years" means that *you are no longer living there*.
- "I have lived" and "I have been living here for twenty years" both mean that *you are still currently living there*. It is twenty years *and counting*.

'Moving house' is, idiomatically, the process of exchanging one house for another, seamlessly. If there were a gap between leaving your old house and going into your new one then you might not use the expression "moving house". You might instead say "I'm moving *into* a new house today".

So, assuming that the exchange is seamless, you must either still be in your old house, or already be in your new house - you cannot be living in both. Therefore either **2** or **3** are correct.

Comment: But if I say "I am moving into a new house  right now" not "today" meaning that I am standing outside the house I am leaving it and I am on my way to my new house would my examples be still wrong to use "I have lived" "I have been living" and "I lived" to say that I am no longer living there?  and in the say way in a similar situation about leaving the office building.   I am leaving the office building right now and I tell my colleague "I have been working," "I have worked" and "I worked" here to mean I  am no longer working there. I just left the office and I am on my way to the new office.